# Constructing a search box in ASP.NET using DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataSet file in an ASP.NET project, and this query works, however I want it to be able to incorporate `LIKE '%'` element. How can I add it into the SQL statement below, while keeping the variable element?

```
SELECT brand, model, location, piclink, colour, price, yearreg, carID 
FROM cars
WHERE brand = ?
```

I tried this but it won't work. Visual Studio claims that its unable to parse query.

```
SELECT brand, model, location, piclink, colour, price, yearreg, carID 
FROM cars
WHERE brand = ? + brand LIKE '%'
```

I have set up a populated drop down box with brand names of cars from an Access database, and I want now to use this modified query to search for results. Can you point me in the right direction, as to where and how to do that, please?

Comment: Change the + to AND. Assume you know LIKE '%' does no filtering (except nulls).

Comment: It parses now, but only returns the results if I type a full name of a car brand for example Audi, and doesn't work if I type Au.

Comment: WHERE brand LIKE '?%'

Comment: Generates but breaks the query. Doesn't know what brand is anymore.

Comment: You could go with LIKE ? and add the % to the end of the parameter.

Comment: How can I add it to the end of the parameter?

Comment: what's your code to add parameter?  Something like da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@myparm", myString + "%")

Comment: see if this helps you out: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access

Comment: i think you're looking for... Like '% yourCriteria %'

Comment: I am adding it in query builder via DataSet.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT brand, model, location, piclink, colour, price, yearreg, carID 
FROM cars
WHERE brand = '?' AND brand LIKE '%'